# Retrieve table to JSON, no matter how many columns in C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I need to build a webservice that only receives a table name.

I was thinking in doing something like this:

```
public class Table
{
    public string field{ get; set; }
    public string value{ get; set; }
}
```

Because I don't know what table the user is going to request and how many columns they have.

I'm using a WCF web service and I want to retrieve the table in JSON format; so far I have something like this (a table with 3 columns):

```
[{"field":"ID","value":"124"},{"field":"DES","value":"AValue"},{"field":"CODE","value":"ACode"},{"field":"ID","value":"125"},{"field":"DES","value":"AnotherV"},{"field":"CODE","value":"AnotherCode"}]
```

As you can see it is difficult to know where a row ends

Is there a way to retrieve the data in a more legible way?

Comment: Why not have a Row and Column object? As it is, you have an array of Tables, which isn't quite what you want

Comment: @Vlad274 could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The model you provided actually models a single cell, not a table.

I suggest you use the following model:

```
public class Row : Dictionary<string,string>
{

}

public class Table : List<Row>
{

}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Table table = new Table
{
    new Row
    {
        {"Name", "Adam"},
        {"Age",  "13"},
        {"Location","USA"} 
    },
    new Row
    {
        {"Name", "James"},
        {"Age", "19"},
        {"Location", "Europe"} 
    }
};
```

Here is an example of how to serialize this object to JSON:

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
```

This code uses [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize the `Table` object into a string.

This will produce the following JSON:

```
[{"Name":"Adam","Age":"13","Location":"USA"},{"Name":"James","Age":"19","Location":"Europe"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be modeling a Table, you need more granularity :

```
public class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Row 
{
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Then to create data:

```
var data = new Table()
               {
                   new Row()
                       {
                           new Column()
                               {
                                   Name = "Name",
                                   Value = "Adam"
                               },
                           new Column()
                               {
                                   Name = "Age",
                                   Value = "13"
                               },
                           new Column()
                               {
                                   Name = "Location",
                                   Value = "USA"
                               }
                       },
                   new Row()
                       {
                           new Column()
                               {
                                   Name = "Name",
                                   Value = "James"
                               },
                           new Column()
                               {
                                   Name = "Age",
                                   Value = "19"
                               },
                           new Column()
                               {
                                   Name = "Location",
                                   Value = "Europe"
                               }
                       }
               }
```

This would then serialize to

```
[
    {
        {
            "Name":"Name",
            "Value":"Adam"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Age",
            "Value":"13"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Location",
            "Value":"USA"
        }
    },
    {
        {
            "Name":"Name",
            "Value":"James"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Age",
            "Value":"19"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Location",
            "Value":"Europe"
        }
    }
]
```

Yes this is more complex, however I prefer because it gives you strongly typed representations of the parts of a Table, but also allows relatively easy access to the data.

@Yacoub-Massad has a good start, and it will get you what you need for the serialization. But I would suggest going all the way because being able to serialize and deserialize to strongly type objects can help catch compile time errors as well as warn you when serialization fails (ie bad data)